# canon pixma g2110 installed incorrectly

Tags: printing, canon, ubuntu-drivers, cups-lpd

I have a canon pixma g2110 which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) automatically detects and installs as a canon G2010 and uses drivers for a generic printer. Therefore I cannot print but I am able to use the scanner. Going through several forums I have found that the printer used to work with previous versions of Ubuntu but have found nothing recent.

I have tried updating the available canon printers with
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
But still I do not get the correct printer driver installed.

Canon officially only has drivers for windows and MAC and I cant find the PPD file to try installing the printer that way.

Apparently CUPS doesn't support the Canon pixma G series. I have version 2.4.1 installed